# The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 7.0. Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 7.0

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, azure-functions

**Note:** This is not a duplicate question despite the title seems like the similar ones.

I am trying to build a docker image to support an Azure Function in .NET 7.0 that works in .NET 6.0 by docker. I have had the following line to pull .NET 6.0

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated6.0
```

I cannot find anything like the following line:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated7.0
```

How can I migrate my azure function to .NET 7.0 in docker?

Answer (score 12):

After I updated the visual studio 2022 issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-dotnet-isolated) official Site, they mentioned dotnet-isolated:4 is supported up to the dotnet-isolated6.0 version and updated on Jan 04, 2023.

[image]

Even in the Official [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#supported-versions) of Azure Functions, it is mentioned only .NET 7 Isolated is released for the Azure Portal Function App deployments.

Yes @Arash, I can see the .NET 7 Isolated in Docker File from VS 2022 IDE after enabling the docker in it:

[image]

[image]

#### Updated Answer:

> Is it possible that .NET 7.0 was released silently: docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated7.0

I can find the .NET 7 release for the Docker Hub in .NET SDK Supported Versions of Docker Hub [Site](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk/) and when it comes to .NET Support for Azure Function Docker Context, I can see only dotnet-isolated6.0 version is supported from these references [1](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-dotnet) & [2](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-dotnet-isolated).

I have also found the issue opened on .NET 7 RC2 Preview on Azure Functions-Isolated Mode in the GitHub Repository of Azure Functions dotnet worker issue #[1119](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1119).

Comment: Thanks Hari, but the following command was successful. Is it possible that .NET 7.0 was released silently: docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated7.0

Comment: I didn't find information on official documents related .NET 7 Azure Functions release for Docker Hub.

Comment: If you scaffold a function app in VS 2022 with .NET 7.0 template you will see that it will generate a docker file that uses 4-dotnet-isolated7.0 tag

Comment: Yes @Arash, I can see the .NET 7 Isolated in Docker File from VS 2022 IDE after enabling the docker in it.

Comment: @Arash, I have updated the answer according to my research, that helps you better.

Comment: even the runtime:6.0 can be changed to runtime7.0